Юнити. Как повернуть объекты своим низом вниз относительно глобального мира?
Скрипт с помощью лучей размещает по стенам объекты. Объекты поворачиваются относительно поверхности стены с помощью transform.up = hit.normal; Мне нужно развернуть все объекты по одной оси (локальный Y) в одну сторону, но относительно своих положений на стенах. Как если бы это были висящие на стенах ткани, слизь, картины, у которых всегда есть верх  и низ. Так же и на не строго вертикальных поверхностях, четко определить где должен быть низ относительно глобального мира, и развернуть объекты своим низом вниз.


Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

transform.localRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal);


пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
